# Verbatim frame latex with no waste

Tags: verbatim

I have a frame/boarder round my Verbatim environment however the frame is extended to the page side, thus alot of wasted space. The following is my code:

```
    \begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
   s=0 
   for j = 1 : i -1 
      s = s + aij * akj
   end 
   aki = (aki - s) / aii 

    \end{Verbatim}
```

Comment: I would like the frame to fit around the code.

Comment: Rather than clarifying in comments, please edit your question to include the information. A complete, compilable, minimal example would also be nice.

Comment: And minimal as in something we can copy and cimpile ourself without having to add anything. Where does `Verbatim` come from, which class is used ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Verbatim` environment from the `fancyvrb` has not an options to do that.

But you can use the similar environment `boxedverbatim` from the `moreverb` package. Remember anyway to eliminate the spaces at the beginning of lines.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moreverb}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedverbatim}
s=0
for j = 1 : i -1
  s = s + aij * akj
end
aki = (aki - s) / aii
\end{boxedverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to add spice to your verbatim later, here is an option with `tcolorbox`. This box can break across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}

\newtcblisting{myverbatim}{
      arc=3mm,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=0mm,
      right=0mm,
      boxrule=0.5pt,
      colback=gray!30,
      listing only,
      hbox,
      breakable
}


\begin{document}

\begin{myverbatim}
s=0
for j = 1 : i -1
  s = s + aij * akj
end
aki = (aki - s) / aii
\end{myverbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

that's not very elegant, but a workaround would be to enclose the Verbatim code with a minipage (the 0.6 should be adapted to your needs)

```
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth} 
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
...
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `verbatimbox` package can also do this.  The nice thing here is that the boxed content is not immidately printed, so that it can then be inserted anywhere a LaTeX box can go.  Here it is inside an `\fbox`, but it can be placed inside a table, a footnote, a section title, etc.

There is also a different environment `myverbbox` in which you provide the name of the recalling macro (different than `\theverbbox`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}
s=0
for j = 1 : i -1
  s = s + aij * akj
end
aki = (aki - s) / aii
\end{verbbox}
\fbox{\theverbbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use `fvextra` along with `fancyvrb`

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
```

This allows for the usage of the `frame=single` parameter you have in your example.